# failed_when with a service vs a command

Tags: ansible

I want to ensure a list of services is disabled if they exist on a system.  By default, many of these services won't exist, but in cases where the service is installed, I want it disabled.

If a service doesn't exist, ansible throws an error.  While I can continue the task with ignore_error, I'm not comfortable with that because it not only masks a real problem, but the error is still shown in the ansible output, and I'd prefer the team not get in the habit of ignoring errors.

I've tried using failed_when, but I don't seem to be able to get it working with a service, and all the examples use command, not service.  Here's the task--disable_services is a list declared elsewhere.

```
- name: "Stop and disable unneeded services"
  service: name={{ item }} enabled=no status=stopped
  failed_when: "'service not loaded' not in stderr"
  with_items: disable_services
```

It fails with the following output:

```
TASK: [hardening | Stop and disable unneeded services] ************************ 
fatal: [host.example.com] => error while evaluating conditional: 'service not loaded' not in stderr
```

I have tried registering the variable service_output, and checking to see that "service not loaded" not in service_output.stderr, but have the same error.

Is it possible to used failed_when on a service, and if so, what Layer 8 problem am I experiencing here?

Comment: I don't think you need `failed_when`. You actually want `ignore_errors` because it's *okay* that it fails. (I do the same thing). I can expand to a full answer if you would like.

Comment: We don't want our deployment team to get in the habit of ignoring errors.  If there's an error, it needs correcting, and we'd rather legitimate errors not be masked.  From what I've seen, ignore_errors still prints the errors, it just proceeds with the implementation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few problems:

1. It's `state`, not `status`.
2. You need to use `register` to bind the result to variable, and then use that variable in `failed_when`.
3. Minor thing: you only check for one kind of failure (it should be OK in this instance, but it's something to keep in mind).

This should work:

```
- name: "Stop and disable unneeded services"
  service: name={{ item }} enabled=no state=stopped
  failed_when: "stop_disabled_services | failed and 'service not found' not in stop_disabled_services.msg"
  register: stop_disabled_services
  with_items: disable_services
```

And a note about how I got this code working:
I've used `ignore_errors` and `debug: var=stop_disable_services` to find what `service` returns on failure. The most interesting part were the items of `stop_disabled_services.results` list, as that's the value of `stop_disable_services` the `failed_when` will see.
From there it was just some Jinja2 to make sure only some failures get ignored.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work.  Very likely this was caused, as you pointed out, by too many potential error messages.  It did solve the initial problem.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I used was different than the marked answer.  The solution listed in this answer solved my problem, but didn't answer the question as I asked so it is **not** the accepted answer.  I think it's a much better approach than my original effort.

I created a command to get the 'installed' services depending on the OS, and register the results as a variable.  I then iterate through an intersection of installed servers and the disabled services.

This is **much** faster than iterating through every potential service and ignoring the error, because only the services I care about are tried.   The list_svcs_cmd is a variable set depending on the OS.

```
---
- name: Get registered services
  shell: "{{ list_svcs_cmd }}"
  register: loaded_services

- name: "Stop and disable unneeded services"
  service: name={{ item }} enabled=no state=stopped
  with_items: disable_services | intersect(loaded_services.stdout_lines)
```

Comment: Can you share the command to list all installed services on windows server ?

Comment: We don't use Windows, and I don't have access to a Windows machine with which I can test. That said, I suspect the `Get-Service` Powershell commandlet would be a good place to start.